# Creating a record for generated numbers in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building an Excel sheet to help me with teaching.

My objective is a sheet to create two random numbers, calculate their arithmetic means and geometric means, and compare them. This part I have finished.

I created a macro and two functions that generates random numbers, then input the numbers to the desired cells:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L1").Value = NewRandom()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M1").Value = NewRandom2()
```

I created a button to execute the macro.

How could I make a record of what I have been generating, in designated area U7:V200, on the same sheet?

My aim: The first time I click the button, two generated numbers will be recorded on U7 and V7, respectively. The second time I click, two generated numbers will be recorded on U8 and V8, and so on.

Comment: Since you're using this as a teaching tool, why not expose some of the spreadsheet logic to the students as well? You can use a cell as an integer counter (increments by one every time the functions are run, so two per button press), and then use the `Offset` [function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) to set the new values into the column according to the value in the integer counter cell.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Search the web for 'Excel VBA find last used row' or similar e.g. https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba. Alternatively as SmrtGrunt suggests use a counter e.g. nextRow = nextRow + 1 after each generation. Use like: 'Range("M" & nextRow) = NewRandom()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subroutine below will find the next empty row based on the "U" column of your sheet.
XLROW signifies the row in which you want to begin your search for an empty row.
Once the empty row is found, the two random values that you have passed to the subroutine will be entered into the first available empty row.

Make sure to change "Sheet1" to the name, if you have one, of the sheet that you are using in excel.

```
Public Sub NEXTEMPTY(VAL1 As Integer, VAL2 As Integer)
Dim XLROW As Integer
XLROW = 7
Do Until Sheet1.Range("U" & XLROW) = ""
    XLROW = XLROW + 1
Loop
Sheet1.Range("U" & XLROW).Value = VAL1
Sheet1.Range("V" & XLROW).Value = VAL2
End Sub
```

Then you can just call the sub anywhere you'd like using:

```
Call NEXTEMPTY(RANDOM1, RANDOM2)
```

EDIT:  You can also use this in the Do Until.  This is more preferable.

```
Do Until IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("U" & XLROW))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a matter of finding the last row and pasting to it...

```
dim lr as long
lr = cells(rows.count,"U").end(xlup).row
cells(lr+1,"U").value = randomnumber1
cells(lr+1,"V").value = randomnumber2
```

Assumes you are always having U/V paired together, so only need 1 last row